# Block Chain Ethereum Error NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blockchain, ethereum

I am integrating Block chain with my Rails App , so I am using Ethereum gem 
  to host the data to the blockchain.

I am getting the below error when i am trying to implement Ethereum to my Rails App.

I am using the following gem [enter link description here](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby)

While i am trying the following command

```
init = Ethereum::Initializer.new("#{ENV['PWD']}/SimpleNameRegistry.sol", client)
```

I am getting the below error

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

when I try to debug inside the gem I received the following error code in the below line.

Error Line:

```
sol_output = @client.compile_solidity(@file)
```

Error Code:

```
{"jsonrpc"=>"2.0", "error"=>{"code"=>-32600, "message"=>"EOF"}}
```

Please help me to get out of this error as I am stuck with this.
  Please also suggest me with an easy implementation of block chain with rails.